# Using GDAL/OGR to remove a specific layer from a geopackage

Tags: gdal, ogr, geopackage

Is there any way to remove some layers from geopackage instead of creating new geopackage with only layers I need.

Example:- I have a geopackage containing:

1. Bars (Point)
2. Bars_reprojected (Point)
3. Metro_reprojected (Point)
4. metro_stations_buffer (Polygon)
5. Metro (Point)

I want to delete Bars (Point) and Metro (Point) from this geopackage.

Comment: Using what software, programming language, or tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with ogrinfo by using the `-sql` option. The usage is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html

> Starting with GDAL 2.2, the “DROP TABLE layer_name” and “ALTER TABLE
> layer_name RENAME TO new_layer” statements can be used. They will
> update GeoPackage system tables.

Updating the system files is important and therefore you should not drop the table with a standard SQLite client like DB Browser.

Notice also this:

> When dropping a table, or removing records from tables, the space they
> occupied is not immediately released and kept in the pool of file
> pages that SQLite may reuse later. If you need to shrink the file to
> its minimum size, you need to issue an explicit “VACUUM” SQL request.
> Note that this will result in a full rewrite of the file.

So run these two commands:

```
ogrinfo -sql "DROP TABLE layer_name" my_geopackage.gpkg
ogrinfo -sql "VACUUM" my_geopackage.gpkg
```

Deleting the layer is very fast but if you want also to shrink the database file then it would be as fast or even faster to create a new geopackage with only the layers that you need.